# Running flutter doctor spits out error: Standard error: fatal: bad object HEAD

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio, installation, version-control

I had installed Flutter and Android Studio from the official websites. I am novice to Git, GitHub, mobile development and android development.

I was trying to run flutter doctor command in the Command Prompt (Windows 10). However, it spits an error in bright red saying:

```
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad --date=iso Standard out: Standard error: fatal: bad object HEAD Returning 1970-01-01 05:30:00.000 instead.
```

---

Plz help me with this issue. I did face network issues while downloading but I resumed the download in time (in Chrome). I do NOT want to reinstall Flutter all over again because of data issues! Also because setting up this whole thing was really enervating!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer might not have worked for you as it didn't work for me too...

I've faced the same issue after installing `flutter-3.10.5-stable` but I've another solution to install Flutter that I used earlier which is currently not available in [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows).

**The Solution:**
**Clone Flutter Repository from GitHub**

Here's how you can do that:

*(Assuming you already have [Git](https://git-scm.com/) installed. If not, download it from [Git website](https://git-scm.com/)!)*

1. Go to any directory where you want Flutter files to be kept
2. Open the terminal in that folder and follow the commands
3. `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` - this fetch all the files that are needed for Flutter to run from [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)
4. Add its bin path `..\flutter\bin` to the *User variables* in the *environment variables*

That should be it. Now you can type `flutter` and `flutter doctor` in the terminal and check if everything works. Try restarting your device if it doesn't work for the first time.

**A few things to remember:**

- The current branch/channel would be `master` which is a development branch (for the developers working on Flutter codebase)
- To change it to `stable` channel (**recommended for users**), use command `flutter channel stable` to switch
- Use command `flutter channel` to check the current channel

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, this is caused by incomplete or corrupted download. You may try the following-

- initiliase the git repo again by-

```sh
git init
```

- then fetch the missing files from the remote, by

```sh
git fetch
```

- If you are facing, some kind of error, like 'your tree is behind HEAD', do-

```sh
git pull
```

- lastly, check the status by

```sh
git status
```

you should get something like this in output-

```
On branch stable
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/stable'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean.
```

Comment: Hey thank for the quick response. Could please tell me how/where I can do that. Sorry to bother, am new to git and development and having a lot of trouble. Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: Where did you install flutter? For instance, I have downloaded and unzipped folder in C:\src\flutter. I would go there, by running, `cd C:\src\flutter` and would execute the commands mentioned above.

Comment: I had installed and extracted flutter in some sub-folder from my Desktop. I don't know where my files got messed up; during download or extraction.

Comment: Then, go to your Desktop and this sub-folder and write `cmd` in your address bar, and hit enter. Then follow the steps mentioned above.

Comment: I also realized by now when I was trying to accept licenses from Android, that I do not have Java although the JDK was installed with Android Studio (during which I faced data balance exhaustion issues which I think resulted in this error!)

Comment: Okay thank you I'll get back to you with the outcome:)

Comment: After passing git pull here's what it is asking me, what do I do?: git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> stable

Comment: try `git pull origin/stable`

Comment: That still didn't work. I tried this `git pull origin/stable` , `git pull origin` , `git pull stable` . I tried them separately and together just in case. Really sorry to bother you with my poor knowledge. This is what it says: `git pull origin/stable
fatal: 'origin/stable' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: I was looking for answers and understood I could also try `git fsck`. Here's the output: `git fsck` git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: refs/heads/stable: invalid sha1 pointer 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
error: HEAD: invalid

Comment: Your `git fsck` errors indicate a damaged repository. It's not clear how badly damaged it is, but you should figure out why it's damaged at all. Did your machine crash and restart unexpectedly? (This can damage the repository.) Did you put the repository on a shared drive? (The sharing software can damage the repository.) etc.

Comment: @torek Thank you for the reply. No my machine didn't cause me any kind of an error while downloading but I guess it was my internet. I had to pause my download in the middle since my data balance was getting over. I then resumed the download the next day when I had enough data balance. I think I might just try and reinstall flutter again :/