# Is there any solution for flutter doctor not running?

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter doctor doesn't work. I added all paths but when I print "flutter doctor" on cmd it shows that:

```
versionCheckError: Command exited with code 128: gti fetch** 
__flutter_version_check__ **stable**
**Standard error: fatal1: unable to access 
'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': could not resolve host: 
github.com
```

then I tried again but it shows that:

**Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...**

and nothing happened
could anyone help me

I added
`C:\\src\\flutter\\bin`
but nothing happened

Comment: I think you should uninstall all your flutter files and then freshly install them again.Go to youtube search for install flutter 2022

Comment: i did it but it still not working

Comment: in cmd it is like that   "Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools..." but nothing hapened

Comment: try to run `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: may be this can work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589945/running-flutter-doctor-spits-out-error-standard-error-fatal-bad-object-head[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589945/running-flutter-doctor-spits-out-error-standard-error-fatal-bad-object-head]

Comment: The link doesn't work so I did as you said before,  I uninstalled all flutter file for the third time and the download it again.. now it's working,  thank you so much 